# Daylight saving ignored when creating a Java Date using new Date(aDate.getTime() + aTime.getTime())

Tags: java, date, timezone

I am currently verifying that a generated Excel sheet contains a correctly-rendered "time stamp" whose date and time part are in separate cells, and whose format is adjusted by a locale.

My test case fails, as when I read back the Excel sheet's time from a String, somehow daylight saving seems to be ignored.

Here's my Java code:

```
    Date now = new Date();

    // [... other code, creating and reading the Excel sheet etc. ...]

    // from an Excel sheet
    String dateString = cellB2.getStringCellValue(); // e.g., 3.7.2013
    String timeString = cellB3.getStringCellValue(); // e.g., 13:38:09

    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault(); // Berlin, CEST
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(tz); // dateFormat is result of DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale); e.g. with locale "cs_CZ"
    timeFormat.setTimeZone(tz); // timeFormat is result of DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale); e.g. with locale "cs_CZ"

    // try to parse the time / date strings using the expected format
    Date actualDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString); // e.g., Wed Jul 03 00:00:00 CEST 2013
    Date actualTime = timeFormat.parse(timeString); // e.g.  Thu Jan 01 13:38:09 CET 1970

    // now: e.g. Wed Jul 03 13:38:09 CEST 2013 
    // actualDateTime: e.g. Wed Jul 03 12:48:07 CEST 2013
    Date actualDateTime = new Date(actualDate.getTime() + actualTime.getTime());
    assertFalse(now.after(actualDateTime)); // fails
```

Comment: First of all I don't like the way you are parsing. I would first concatenate both input strings (with a space between them) and then make only one parse. I'm not 100% sure what happens when you parse a time without date values, might it be that it takes the current Date as default, or will it really consider 0 + timeConversion? I would like to see what actualDate and ActualTime return if you format them... Has this code worked previously?

Comment: No, the code has not worked before.

About using only one parse: I could not find a way to get the pattern from the DateFormats without casting - is there any?

Comment: About parsing a time-only String, you may be right: the comment shows actualTime seems to be off one hour (CET instead of CEST), but I wonder if that can be prevented. Obviously, setTimeZone() did not work.

Comment: And then it hit me: as 1 Jan is not a date that would be in daylight saving time, it's CET instead of CEST. That is the cause of my problem. I will change my code and provide a corrected version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following both Martin's and Matt's suggestions, here is my final program snippet:

```
    // from an Excel sheet
    String dateString = cellB2.getStringCellValue();
    String timeString = cellB3.getStringCellValue();

    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault(); 

    // NEW!
    DateFormat dateTimeFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM, l); 
    dateTimeFormat.setTimeZone(tz);

    Date actualDateTime = dateTimeFormat.parse(dateString + " " + timeString);
    assertFalse(now.after(actualDateTime));
```

Answer (score 2):

Robert,

Your solution will work, but I think it's like making one workaround around another and it makes your code more complex, thus harder to mantain. Why not use a SimpleDateFormat with this pattern:

```
"dd.MM.YYYY kk:mm:ss"
```

Then, just make a Date String like this:

```
String dateTime = cellB2.getStringCellValue() + " " + cellB3.getStringCellValue();
```

Then you can parse it... I did not actually test it, but it should give you the idea, maybe you need to check the pattern String, here's the reference:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Regards

Comment: The patterns are part of my input: They are retrieved using  DateFormat.getDateInstance(...) and DateFormat.getTimeInstance(...). But I guess I'll give DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(...) a shot instead - otherwise, I would have to cast DateFormat to SimpleDateFormat or something, I would not like to do that.

Comment: Why not use SimpleDateFormat instead? So you can pass the pattern in the constructor and make it behave just as you need it. It would look line SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY kk:mm:ss"); You don't need to cast anything...

Comment: There are other nuances that can come up when parsing separately, so I strongly recommend this approach.  For example, what happens if the date at midnight is part of an ambiguous DST roll-back transition, but is fine at the specific time?  There are certainly time zones that transition at midnight (Brazil, for example).

Comment: My use case is strongly focused on getting a DateFormat (not: SimpleDateFormat, I would have to do casting etc. ...) from a locale, as shown in the example. For this reason, I will prefer my final solution using DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(...) to do the parsing, as opposed to creating a custom SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 0):

After setting actualTime, I have to make the following distinction:

```
    if (tz.inDaylightTime(actualDate)) {
        actualTime = new Date(actualTime.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60);
    }
```

As the time-only String will always result in a Date on 1 January 1970, daylight saving will never be considered (at least not for my Berlin case), and I have to make adjustments manually.

Comment: Actually, some time zones *were* in daylight saving during 1/1/1970.  Specifically, UK was on BST instead of GMT.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Date in java does not add daylight savings time automatically.  This is because java Date is calculated by epoch (the number of seconds since January 1, 1970), and represents UTC time.

If you want the class you're using to automatically correct for daylight savings time you can either use the built in Calendar class or, [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).  I'd really recommend taking a look at Joda Time.  Its better than java.util.Date java.sql.Date and java.util.Calendar combined!  It so much easier to deal with one really complete time library than deal with 3 different ones and try to convert between them.

Also, just as a funny aside that shows how difficult DST can be, see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84aWtseb2-4) - at about the 4 minute mark it explains how different countries implement DST and what a headache this causes for everyone.