# C# DateTime not correct

Tags: java, c#, android, datetime

I have a problem with the difference in getting the time which has arisen this week, possibly due to Daylight Savings Time in the U.S. There is an hour difference in C# and Java (Android). I want the Java to behave the same as the C#.

Windows 10 - C#

```
value = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan span = (value - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime());
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("span: " + (int)span.TotalSeconds);
```

Unix epoch seconds:
1489764265
Which converts to:
Fri, 17 Mar 2017 15:24:25 GMT

Java - Android Studio - Run on Samsung T5330-NU

```
Date date = new Date(); // current date and time
Integer.toString(ConvertToTimestamp(date))
```

Unit epoch seconds:
1489760686
Which converts to:
Fri, 17 Mar 2017 14:24:46 GMT

The seconds (:25 vs :46) is fine.
The hours are the problem  (15 vs 14)
Somehow daylight savings time must be involved.

What can be done?

Using this to convert Unix epoch time:
http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Edit:
Original Java code gets current date/time like so:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Based on the comment by @AkosNagy, I tried:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST"));
```

and

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("MDT"));
```

but there is no difference.

Edit:
Changed the title because this is in the end a question about C# and why the C# is not giving the correct time.

Edit:
This is the line I was looking for:

```
Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: What's the value of `value`?

Comment: added code to show

Comment: Maybe these can help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545960/how-to-tackle-daylight-savings-using-timezone-in-java

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447481/daylight-saving-ignored-when-creating-a-java-date-using-new-dateadate-gettime

One of the answer is from Jon Skeet, so it must be good :)

Comment: `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime()` isn't returning what you think it is. You need to specify the timezone, somehow (I'm not a C# guy, I don't know how). Remember that 1970/1/1 00:00:00.000 in London is actually 1970/1/1 01:00:00.000 UTC.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I can't change the C# code, only the Java/Android.

Comment: @AlLelopath your C# code is wrong, or your computer's clock is wrong: it isn't Fri, 17 Mar 2017 15:24:25 GMT yet.

Comment: General guidelines for DateTime calculations (esp. for places that have daylight saving time): 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx#datetime_sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(CHECK EDIT BELOW)

In c#, `DateTime.Now` returns the local time of your computer so time zones don't matter, as you can see in [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

For java, I found [these code snippets](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/) which use other methods like `LocalDateTime.now()`.

EDIT:

after reading your answer again, I understood that your problem is with the c# code. that is my solution:
instead of that Unix epoch seconds thing:

```
value = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan span = (value - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime());
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("span: " + (int)span.TotalSeconds);
```

just use this:

```
//first, get the corrent time
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
//print the time
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString());
// For en-US culture, for other culture type refer to MSDN link
//output mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/pm
```

If you realy need the Unix epoch seconds, refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632584/how-to-get-the-unix-timestamp-in-c-sharp)
also check your system clock.

Hope I helped!

EDIT: I changed the link to what you needed

Comment: Do you mean `date.ToString()`, not `date1`?

Comment: Not exactly. I do need Unix epoch seconds. Following the link you provided I [ended up here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632584/how-to-get-the-unix-timestamp-in-c-sharp) and the line of code in the accepted answer is what I need. Please put that link in your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I changed the link in  answer

Answer (score 3):

`new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime()` isn't returning what you think it is. You need to specify the timezone:

```
new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToLocalTime()
```

1970/1/1 00:00:00.000 in London was actually 1970/1/1 01:00:00.000 UTC (we were in permanent daylight savings at Unix epoch).

---

Or your computer's clock/timezone may be wrong. After all, you posted your code before `Fri, 17 Mar 2017 15:24:25 GMT` (it was about `Fri, 17 Mar 2017 14:40:00 GMT`).

But in any case, it makes the code more robust to specify the UTC timezone, since you won't be dependent upon the local computer's configuration.

Comment: I've tried as you've suggest in C#. It behaves the same. Hmph.

Comment: Have you checked your computer's clock?

Comment: The computer is adjusted for Daylight Savings Time. The C# and the computer time match (and are correct). The Java/Android is an hour behind. The Android device time matches the C# and computer.

Comment: I'll say again: *it isn't Fri, 17 Mar 2017 15:24:25 GMT yet*. London is not yet in daylight savings, and it's currently 15:03 GMT by my watch.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right. Let me think ... Still the code you suggested makes no difference. That puzzles me.

Comment: As stated, the 2 lines return the same value (inocrrect, 1 hour ahead). 
Would the result of the 2nd be different if we were in Standard time (as opposed to Daylight Savings Time, as we are now.)